# Proof of inscribed angle theorem for special case

Tags: geometry

The proof for the other cases are trivial and I understood them fast, but this one I just can't figure out how to proof. I would appreciate a good hint.

Inscribed angle:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $Q$ be the point where $\overline{MP}$ meets $\overline{AB}$. The angle sums of $\triangle MAQ$ and $\triangle PBQ$ (and those of $\triangle MBQ$ and $\triangle PAQ$) are equal. Now, do some angle-chasing based on isosceles triangles in the figure.

---

**More-than-a-Hint.** Here's the situation for $\triangle PAQ$ and $\triangle MBQ$, showing that $\angle BMP = 2\angle BAP$:

[image]

Comment: I feel embarrassed but I still can't figure it out. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Thank you and enjoy the coffee!

Comment: @Isos: Glad to help! (Thanks for my very first coffee! :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: For $\phi_1$, consider extending $\overline{MB}$ to get a diameter. Is the case of an inscribed angle with one side along a diameter one of the "trivial" other cases?